# How to measure insert time?

Tags: kdb

Using the kx pacakge to do a bulk insert, how do I measure the insertion time, excluding network latency?

```
KdbConnection.c.ks("insert", table, flip);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible you should be able to replace your "insert" with the following

`"{start:.z.p;x insert y;.z.p - start}"`

essentially define a start time, do your insert, and then return the difference between the start and current time.
 if you also have direct access to the q session you could also try something like

`` \t:10 `table_name insert data ``

in the session to return the time it takes to do 10 (or whatever number is needed) run throughs of insert.
One thing to bare in mind: the former method will return in nanosecond format, the latter in milisecond (hence why we do 10, or more if needed, iterations of it).

Cheers,

Sean